# bxSlider duplicates wrapper on reloadSlider()

Tags: bxslider

I'm trying to make the slider to dynamically change slide amount (maxslide/minslide) using the `reloadSlider()`. But it duplicates the wrapper.

The interesting thing is that it duplicates not always and sometime displays correctly (I mean after reloading the browser page).

Here are my poor lines:

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function(){

  // init product slider
  if($('.slider-product-wrap').length>0){
  var slider_product=$('.slider-product-wrap .slider').bxSlider();      

  // product slider sets
  function sliderProduct(){

    var slideAmount=3;   

    // slide amount depends on window's width
    if($(window).width()<1000 && $(window).width()>=500) slideAmount=2;
    else if($(window).width()<500) slideAmount=1; 

    // set custom settings;
      slider_product.reloadSlider({
        minSlides: slideAmount,
        maxSlides: slideAmount,
        auto: false,
        slideWidth: 364,
        slideMargin: 28, 
        pause: 5000,
        nextText:'',
        prevText:'',
        autoHover: true,
        autoStart: true,
        pager: false,
        controls: true        
      });
  }

  sliderProduct(); // create new slider

  // reload slider to make it responsive
  $(window).resize(function(){ 
    sliderProduct(); 
  }); 
} 
}(jQuery));
```

I believe there is a smart solution so I'm waiting for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you get intermittent behavior, it's probably load timing issues. When creating DOM elements such as `div.bx-wrapper` and `div.bx-viewport` bxSlider (and the majority of jQuery plugins as well), need a little more time. I like to use callbacks or a small timeout because it gives me a placeholder in the chain of events.
Here's a demo of what I believe you wanted: [bxSlider Reloads on Resize](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/Lt0ref40/5/).

The changes are as follows:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('.bxWrap').length > 0) {
            var bxSlider = $('.bxWrap .bxSlider').bxSlider();
        }

        function bxInit() {
            var winSize = $(window).width(),
                sizeID;
            if (winSize < 1000 && winSize >= 500) {
                sizeID = 2;
            } else if (winSize < 500) {
                sizeID = 1;
            } else {
                sizeID = 3;
            }
            bxSlider.reloadSlider({
                minSlides: sizeID,
                maxSlides: sizeID,
                moveSlides: sizeID,
                auto: true,
                slideWidth: 364,
                slideMargin: 28,
                pause: 5000,
                nextText: '',
                prevText: '',
                autoHover: true,
                autoStart: true,
                autoDelay: 750,
                pager: false
            });
        }

        bxInit();

        $(window).resize(function () {
            bxSlider.stopAuto(true);
            bxInit();
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

I changed the names because it's easier for me to associate objects with a common prefix. I added the `autoDelay` option which gives bxSlider the extra time to reload. On the resize event i added `autoStop` before the `bxInit()` function starts (that's your `sliderProduct()`).
It works the first time I fired it up and I checked for the extra divs and found none. Btw, I also added the option `moveSlides` so when it's at 3 slides it'll move 3 at a time, 2 moves 2, 1 moves 1. On horizontal carousels, it runs smoother when the slides are shown then hidden rather than shown 2 or 3 times then hidden. Good luck.

Comment: @FredMer, No problem. Did I resolve your problem or at least put you on the right path? If so, mark your question as answered.